# ExtJS 4.2 tooltip sometimes cannot display all messages in IE8

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, tooltip

In ExtJS 4.2, I use tooltip in a grid panel, it works in Chrome but sometimes cannot display all messages in IE8. The width is enough to handle the content and some of cells can be displayed normally, others cannot and it seems to be no regularity here.

[Image](http://i58.tinypic.com/20kyoag.png) is displayed normally:

[image: normal]

[Image](http://i58.tinypic.com/an0kk7.png) isn't displayed normally:

[image: not_normal]

Code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    viewConfig: {
        enableTextSelection: true
    },
    title: 'This is title',
    renderTo: 'nameOfGrid', 
    forceFit: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    store: nameOfStore,     
    columns: [
        { text: '...', dataIndex: '...', sortable: true, flex: 0.25},
        { text: '...', dataIndex: '...', sortable: true, flex: 0.25 },
        { text: '...', dataIndex: '...', sortable: true, flex: 0.35 }
    ],
    bbar: new Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        id:'pagingtoolbar',
        pageSize: 25,
        store: nameOfStore,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: ' Display {0}-{1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: 'No more data...'
    }),
    listeners: {
        viewready:showTooltip
    },
    buttons: [
        { 
            text: '<font color=white><strong>Button1</strong></font>',
            handler: promoteReferenceData 
        }, {
            text: '<font color=white><strong>Button2</strong></font>',
            handler: removeReferenceData
        }, {
            text: '<font color=white><strong>Button3</strong></font>',
            handler:function() {
                window.location.href = url
            }
        }
    ]
});

function showTooltip(grid) {
    var view = grid.view;
    this.toolTip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: view.el,
        delegate: view.cellSelector,
        trackMouse: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            beforeshow: function(tip) {
                var trigger = tip.triggerElement,
                parent = tip.triggerElement.parentElement,
                columnTitle = view.getHeaderByCell(trigger).text,
                columnDataIndex = view.getHeaderByCell(trigger).dataIndex,
                columnText = view.getRecord(parent).get(columnDataIndex).toString();
                if (columnText) {
                    tip.update("<b>" + columnTitle + ":</b> " + columnText);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```